# How to detect temporary failures in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, mysql-python

I'm writing a python utility to perform a lot of requests on a MySQL server. One of the requirement is to retry a query (after some time) if we detect a temporary failure (for example if the network is temporary down). We use [MySQL Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/).

The basic idea is:

```
try:
    cursor = cnx.get_cursor()
except:
    # If error is temporary, wait and retry
    # else stop
try:  
    cursor.execute(request)
except:
    # If error is temporary, wait and retry
    # else stop
```

The creation of the cursor and the request are handled separately to ease error handling.

The issue is that it seems hard to detect the cases where it's worth retrying. AFAI, the mapping between MySQL errors and [PEP 249 errors](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#exceptions) in MysQL Connector/Python is not easy to work with. For instance, error `2013` (lost connection to server) is mapped to `InterfaceError` while error `2006` (server has gone away) is mapped to `OperationalError` while both are cases where it is worth retrying.

So I was wondering if there is a conventional way (probably based on the `errno`) to classify such errors.

Comment: Sorry I forgot one important word in the title.

Comment: There's a typo in your bounty, should be "list" not "least".  Had me confused for a second.

Comment: If you are using transactions, the try/except needs to encompass the entire transaction; this will take care of deadlocks, etc.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell Sorry for the typo. Do you know how to correct it ?

Comment: I'd say the notion of a "temporary" error is rather application-specific and it might make sense to make a custom `is_worth_retrying` function (which, perhaps, could also specify the wait period, depending on the issue).

The "server has gone away" error, for example, is certainly an OperationalError as it means your query executes too long beyond the server's patience. Is it worth retrying or should you rewrite the query or reconfigure the server? Up to you to decide.

Comment: In general I'd suspect for most people the only reason for considering retrying would be a "lost connection", and even there you'd probably have to configure timeouts and retry counts depending on your personal expectations and circumstances. More often you'd set up the "retry" logic higher up the chain (e.g. provide the user with a "retry" button in the UI).

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

for i in range(0,100):
    while True:
        try:
            result = sock.connect_ex(('irc.myserver.net', 6667))
            if result == 0:
                break
            else:
                continue
```

can you try this kind of thing before or after doing data transfer you can check connectivity between database then if all the things are OK you can execute query

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you have to write your own class to handle this.
This code is in alpha/beta.

Helpful comments,suggestions, or etc helpful.

For example:
this thread safe?
Is this multi-class safe?

Usage:

connection = mysqlc.Mysql(host='192.168.1.1', user='user', password='password', database='database')

The connection.sql(sql) command tries its best to handle errors automatically.

----------Class------------------

```
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import mysql

import mysql.connector



class Mysql(object):
    __instance = None

    __host = None
    __user = None
    __password = None
    __database = None

    __session = None
    __connection = None

    def __new__(cls, host,user,password,database,*args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.__instance:
            cls.__instance = super(Mysql, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', user='root', password='', database=''):
        self.__host = host
        self.__user = user
        self.__password = password
        self.__database = database

    #Open connection with database
    def _open(self):
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=self.__host, user=self.__user, password=self.__password,
                                          database=self.__database)
            self.__connection = cnx
            self.__session = cnx.cursor()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                print('Something is wrong with your user name or password')
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                print('Database does not exists')
            elif err.errno == 2003:
                print("No connection to host")
            else:
                print("Some other error" )
# err 1698 access denied
                print(err)

    def _close(self):
        self.__session.close()
        self.__connection.close()

    def sql(self, sql, *args, **kwargs):
        values = None
        arg=len(args)
        kwarg=len(kwargs)
        if self.__connection is None:
           self._open() 
        self.__connection.ping(reconnect=True,attempts=3,delay=2)
        while True:
            try:
                 if arg == 0 and kwarg ==0:
                    self.__session.execute(sql)
                 if arg == 1 and kwarg == 0:
#                    self.__session.execute(temp)
                    self.__session.execute(sql, args[0])

            except InterfaceError as err:
                       self._open()
            except OprationalError as err:
                       self._open()
            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
#                 print("err:")
#                 print(+err.errno)
                 print("error")
                 print(format(err))
                 if err.errno == -1:
                     self._open()

                 if err.errno ==2003:
                     try:
                          self.__connection.ping(reconnect=True,attempts=3,delay=2)
                     except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                          print("error")
                          print(err.errno)
                          self._open()
            except:
                   print(sys.exc_info()[0])
            else:
                self.__connection.commit()
                break


        #row=self.__session.fetchall()
        #print(row)
#        self.__connection.commit()
        return self.__session.lastrowid
```